# Linking dynamic dll from another dll causes error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, dynamic-linking

I'm building a project using Visual C++ 2013 where i have one global shared library that all other projects should include. This library project contains only two files called "utils.h" and "utils.cpp".

Inside the utils.h file I have the following code declared.

```
#ifndef CLASS_UTIL
#define CLASS_UTIL

#ifdef _WINDLL
#if defined(LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_STATIC)
#define LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API
#elif defined(LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_EXPORTS)
#define LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif /* LIBCIIFILE_STATIC */
#else //NOT WINDOWS DLL
#define LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API 
#endif

#include "options.h"
#include "global_constants.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl string_to_double(const std::string& s);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl strict_str2double(char* str);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl getParNm(int num, string* element);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl calcDistance(double* delta);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl calcDistance(double* coords1, double* coords2);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl calc_angle(double*, double*);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API void _cdecl correct_coordinates(double* coords, Options_t opt);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API double _cdecl getDN(double diameter, Options_t opt);

LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API string _cdecl get_support_direction(double *delta, string support_type, Options_t opt);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API string _cdecl getSupportDesc(double id);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API void _cdecl eraseSupport(string element[]);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API void _cdecl set_control_limits(string element[]);
LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_API void _cdecl load_default_diameter_par(double *&nominal, double *&real, int &array_size);

#endif
```

Then on the project settings i've included **LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_EXPORTS** on the preprocessor definitions

On my second project, which is another dynamic dll, i just include the utils.h **without** defining **LIBCIIEXPORTSHARED_EXPORTS** and i get the following errors.

```
1>database_table.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl getParNm(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (__imp_?getParNm@@YANHPAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall DBtable::set_db_data(class Element_Manager *,class Bend *,struct Options_t)" (?set_db_data@DBtable@@QAEXPAVElement_Manager@@PAVBend@@UOptions_t@@@Z)
1>element.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl getParNm(int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *)" (__imp_?getParNm@@YANHPAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>database_table.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl calcDistance(double *)" (__imp_?calcDistance@@YANPAN@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall DBtable::set_db_data(class Element_Manager *,class Bend *,struct Options_t)" (?set_db_data@DBtable@@QAEXPAVElement_Manager@@PAVBend@@UOptions_t@@@Z)
1>database_table.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) double __cdecl getDN(double,struct Options_t)" (__imp_?getDN@@YANNUOptions_t@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall DBtable::set_db_data(class Element_Manager *,class Bend *,struct Options_t)" (?set_db_data@DBtable@@QAEXPAVElement_Manager@@PAVBend@@UOptions_t@@@Z)
1>element.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl correct_coordinates(double *,struct Options_t)" (__imp_?correct_coordinates@@YAXPANUOptions_t@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Element_Manager::set_data_from_file(class DBtable *,class CIIFile *,struct Options_t)" (?set_data_from_file@Element_Manager@@QAEXPAVDBtable@@PAVCIIFile@@UOptions_t@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Nando\Documents\Projetos\05-rmc-ciiexport\code\Debug\libciifile++.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

I've checked that both projects are set to *Use Unicode Character Set* and the first one is marked as a Project dependency of the second one.

I've also checked that the .h directory is included on the *Additional Include Directories* in the project settings

What do I need to change on visual studio settings so that the DLL is linked?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the directory the **lib** file of the dll resides in, and the name of the lib file to link against

Add the **path** of your lib file. it is usually (but not required) to be in the same directory as the dll you are trying to link against.

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

Add the lib **file** to the dependency list

Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Comment: That did it. What I don't understand is. I've downloaded the libconfig++ from http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/ and I didn't have to do that. Don't really know why visual studio doesn't just include these references when you set a project as a dependency from another. But well. That's a question for another day. Thanks.

Comment: I have used headers from libraries that have used #pragmas to do automatic linking before. I imagine libconfig++ does something to that effect, but I am not familiar with how its done.

Answer (score 1):

When you build the DLL it produces a .lib file. You need to link this lib file into each project that will use the DLL. The lib contains stub functions that satisfy the linker.

Comment: I get that. You see, i'm using visual studio 2013 as the IDE for my project. What am I missing from the IDE perspective so that the DLL lib is linked correctly in my project.